# how to push object to array object in javascripts?

Tags: javascript

how to push object to array object in javascripts?
I have data array object like data 1 below, and I want to push multiple data object like data 2 below become data result, how to do that?

data 1:

```
[ {
    _id: 5b4ef851e1e5b938489cb952,
    name: 'Stanlee',
    data: 2,
    __v: 0 },
  { 
    _id: 5b4ef717e1e5b938489cb94e,
    name: 'Jhone ',
    data: 2,
    __v: 0 },
  { 
    _id: 5b4ee85b81bf2115b8ae0a8d,
    name: 'Sushio',
    data: 2,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

data 2:

```
[{ id: 2,
  name: 'transportation',
  type: 'car'},
{ id: 2,
  name: 'transportation',
  type: 'motor'},
{ id: 2,
  name: 'transportation',
  type: 'train'}]
```

data result :

```
[ {
    _id: 5b4ef851e1e5b938489cb952,
    name: 'Stanlee',
    data: { id: 2,
            name: 'transportation',
            type: 'car'}
    __v: 0 },
  { 
    _id: 5b4ef717e1e5b938489cb94e,
    name: 'Jhone ',
    data: { id: 2,
            name: 'transportation',
            type: 'motor'}
    __v: 0 },
  { 
    _id: 5b4ee85b81bf2115b8ae0a8d,
    name: 'Sushio',
    data: { id: 2,
            name: 'transportation',
            type: 'train'}
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do that with `data1.forEach((x, i) => x.data = data2[i] || x.data);`

Try it below:

```js
var data1 = [{
    _id: "5b4ef851e1e5b938489cb952",
    name: 'Stanlee',
    data: 2,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5b4ef717e1e5b938489cb94e",
    name: 'Jhone ',
    data: 2,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5b4ee85b81bf2115b8ae0a8d",
    name: 'Sushio',
    data: 2,
    __v: 0
  }
];

var data2 = [{
    id: 2,
    name: 'transportation',
    type: 'car'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'transportation',
    type: 'motor'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'transportation',
    type: 'train'
  }
];

data1.forEach((x, i) => x.data = data2[i] || x.data);
console.log(data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d1=[{a:1},{a:1},{a:3}];
var d2=[{a:4},{a:5}];

document.write("Data 1 : " + JSON.stringify(d1) +"<br/>");

document.write("Data 2 : " + JSON.stringify(d2) +"<br/>");

d2.forEach(function(obj) {
  d1.push(obj);
});

document.write("Data 1 : " + JSON.stringify(d1));
```